# Correlation between top 10 cryptocurrencies?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have time series data for top 10 cryptocurrencies including these features:

open, close, high, low, volume.

1). I want to know which method is better for correlation testing between them - Pearson's Correlation or Spearman Correlation? Why?

2). Correlation should be tested for which price - low, high, open, close, average?

3). Since it is time series data, for testing correlation how much time period data is required(minimum)?

Comment: Hi this looks more like an Project. 
For the Time-series you can use influxdb https://www.influxdata.com 
for the analyse python pandas

Comment: Possibly related (because you appear to be asking about corr( price_it, price_jt ) for two different financial assets i and j):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555540/does-it-really-matter-if-a-correlation-is-spurious

Comment: Also related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133155/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-correctly-with-time-series

Comment: @Adrian I already read those solutions but here I am asking in context with cryptocurrencies means they don't follow the assumptions of pearson correlation (normaility). Also please could you answer other two questions as well.